# Evento Onclick y AJAX para actualizar base de datos

Tags: ajax

Quiero realizar lo siguiente. Al pulsar sobre un enlace, se ejecute un evento `onclick` y que con AJAX se actualice la base de datos.

Código PHP

```
if ($mencion['seccion'] == "noticia") {
   if ($mencion['leido'] == 0) {
      echo sprintf(
        '<a class="mencion" rel="nofollow" data-idmencion="%s" data-id="%s" data-foro="%s" data-subforo="%s" data-asunto="%s" data-pagina="%s" class="leido" href="%s"><strong>%s</strong></a>',
         $id_mencion,
         $id_hilo,
         str_replace(" ", "%",$mencion['foro']),
         $mencion['subforo'],
         limpia_url($informacion_hilo[0]['titulo']),
         $mencion['pagina_hilo'],
         $ruta . "noticia/" . $id_hilo . "/" . limpia_url($informacion_hilo[0]['titulo']) . "/",
         $informacion_hilo[0]['titulo']
      );
      ?>
      <script>
         document.querySelector('.mencion').addEventListener('click', function leido (event) {
         var idmencion = this.dataset.idmencion
         // Prevent the default link behaviour, i.e. the redirect
         event.preventDefault()

         $.ajax ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process_leido.php',
            data: { "idmencion": idmencion },
            success: function(data){
            location.href = "<?php echo $ruta ?>noticia/" + idmencion + "/<?php echo limpia_url($informacion_hilo[0]['titulo']) ?>/";
         }
       })
      })
      </script>
      <?php
   } else {
       echo "<a class='mencion' rel='nofollow' href=''>" . $informacion_hilo[0]['titulo'] . "</a>";
   }
}
```

Esto me genera el siguiente código HTML:

```
<a class="mencion" rel="nofollow" data-idmencion="56" data-id="161" data-foro="-" data-subforo="-" data-asunto="Need-For-Speed-Payback-lo-nuevo-de-Ghost-Games-y-Electronic-Arts" data-pagina="0" href="http://localhost/xboxone/noticia/161/Need-For-Speed-Payback-lo-nuevo-de-Ghost-Games-y-Electronic-Arts/" style="color: rgb(124, 6, 32);"><strong>Need For Speed Payback, lo nuevo de Ghost Games y Electronic Arts</strong></a>
```

El código donde se ejecuta AJAX:

```
session_start();

require 'admin/config.php';

try {
   $conexion = new PDO($bd_config['dbname'], $bd_config['usuario'], $bd_config['password'] );
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$id = isset($_POST['idmencion'])? $_POST['idmencion'] : 0;

$statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE menciones SET leido = 1 WHERE id = :id");
$statement->execute(array(":id" => $id));
```

Comment: No queda claro cuál es tu problema. Aparentemente solo te genera el enlace del else, probablemente porque $mencion['leido'] es distinto de 0... Puedes aclarar un poco más tu problema?

Comment: y el problema es?

Comment: @AngelCid Genera el enlace del if, no del else. El problema es que no me actualiza la base de datos.

Comment: Lo más probable es que no te llegue el id, ya que estás navegando a una URL en lugar de enviar un formulario. Te sugiero que acabes el **href** del enlace con **?idmencion={id}** y que en el PHP leas el parámetro como **_GET['idmencion']**

Comment: @AngelCid Prefiero no enviar esos datos por la URL, no son peligrosos pero prefiero que sólo funcione a través de los enlaces de la base de datos. He quitado la etiqueta href, pero no me redirige a la URL a través de Ajax. Se supone que el formulario lo estoy enviando a través de POST, aunque no soy un entendido de esto.

Answer (score 1):

Un enlace de tipo < a href> no envia un POST al controlador de la url asociada. Por lo tanto, no vas a poder leer en la parte de servidor el parametro con POST. Puedes hacerlo de estas maneras:

**ENVIO DE UN GET CON ENLACE**

La forma para hacer esto con un enlace es que se genere con un parametro en la url, tal como:

```
<a href="http://localhost/MyGame?idmencion=10"><strong>Delete</strong></a>
```

Con esto, al php le llegara en el _GET el campo idmencion con el valor 10. Puedes recojerlo con:

```
$id = isset($_GET['idmencion'])? $_GET['idmencion'] : 0;
```

**ENVIO PUT EN FORM**

Si nos ponemos un poco mas extrictos, lo mas correcto seria enviar un formulario con el metodo PUT hacia la url. Tu codigo, en lugar de generar un enlace deberia generar algo como:

```
<form method="PUT" action="http://localhost/MyGame">
<input type="hidden" name="idmencion" value="10">
<input type="submit"> name="borrar">
</form>
```

Y en tu php, controlar el metodo PUT:

```
if ($_METHOD="PUT") {
    $id = isset($_REQUEST['idmencion'])? $_REQUEST['idmencion'] : 0;

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE menciones SET leido = 1 WHERE id = :id");
    $statement->execute(array(":id" => $id));
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Esto es lo que he pensado en el caso de que no encuentre la forma con AJAX, pero prefiero no pasarlo por GET, porque entonces lo puedes meter manualmente  y aunque sea poco probable, dar como leída una notificación cuando no ha sido así, aunque estés en la URL correcta donde tienes la mención. Prefiero que el estado a leído pase a verdadero sólo a través de la URL.